# PHP: White parts of image files turns slightly beige after upload/resize

Tags: php, image

So I've been looking around for a while for an answer to my problem and can never find exactly what I need.

The problem with my upload functions is that whenever an image as some pure white (Exemple: an image with only a background of #FFF) the output image's white section are yellowish/beige.

Looking at the image in Photoshop I noticed that it now include some pixels that are now #FEFEFE in those sections. (couldn't determine the proportion).

My client's website as a white background and those uploaded images stick out instead of being seamless.

Incidentally, I've tried using imagepng instead of imagejpg with the same results (and a much bigger file).

Thanks for your help

Here is the code (I've remove a lot of comments to make it readable, might have shopped off some } and such. I can assure you there are no syntax error in the original code.) :

```
    // FILE NAME
    // Random number will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

    $ImageName      = strRemoveAccents($_FILES['ImageFile']['name']);
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($ImageName)); //get image name

    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // get original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Temp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //get file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    //Let's check allowed $ImageType, we use PHP SWITCH statement here
    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            //Create a new image from file 
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $CreatedImage = @imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            die('Type de fichier non-supporté!'); //output error and exit
    }

    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);

    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

    $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;

    //set the Destination Image
    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumbnail name with destination directory
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; // Image with destination directory

    //Resize image to Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    $resizeOk = resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,100,$ImageType);     

    if($resizeOk) {
        //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
        $cropOk = cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType);
        if(!$cropOk) {
            echo 'Erreur lors de la création du thumbnail.';
        }

        $titre = $_POST['imageTitle'];

    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }
} 


// This function will proportionally resize image 
function resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$MaxSize,$DestFolder,$SrcImage,$Quality,$ImageType)
{
    //Check Image size is not 0
    if($CurWidth <= 0 || $CurHeight <= 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $ImageScale         = min($MaxSize/$CurWidth, $MaxSize/$CurHeight); 
    $NewWidth           = ceil($ImageScale*$CurWidth);
    $NewHeight          = ceil($ImageScale*$CurHeight);
    $NewCanves          = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);

    // Resize Image
    if(imagecopyresampled($NewCanves, $SrcImage,0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $CurWidth, $CurHeight))
    {
        switch(strtolower($ImageType))
        {
            case 'image/png':
                imagepng($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                imagegif($NewCanves,$DestFolder);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                imagejpeg($NewCanves,$DestFolder,$Quality);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    //Destroy image, frees memory   
    if(is_resource($NewCanves)) {imagedestroy($NewCanves);} 
    return true;
    }

}
```